# How can I buy things with monthly payments in the US?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, interest, payment

I am a new international student in the US. In our country we didn't have credit cards like in the US and this is a new system to me.

If I get a new credit card in the US with a $2000 credit line/limit and want to buy something whose price is $1000, and I want to do the payment like $100 per month for 10 months (with no extra interest), how can I do it? What is the procedure and the mechanism?

Comment: Also be aware that most, if not all, credit cards charge very high interest on unpaid balances.  The current average is 16.13% (https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/rate-report/ )  You MAY be able to get a card that has an introductory 0% rate, but I think those are only offered to people with good credit ratings.

Comment: **You** specifically, are very unlikely to just get a free loan. You would have to qualify for a 0% APR credit card, pay minimum monthly payments (or larger), and pay off the entire balance before the grace period expires. These offers are usually extended to people with existing good credit. See https://www.nerdwallet.com/best/credit-cards/low-interest

Comment: Also: DON'T! It's a trap to get you hooked in an endless cycle of debt, consumerism and paycheck to paycheck living

Comment: Even if you do qualify for a 0% introductory rate, you have to be really careful. A lot of times they come with the stipulation that if you don't pay off the entire balance by the end of introductory period, you will owe a very high interest rate calculated against the original balance. Read the fine print, then read it again.

Comment: @DeepDeadpool: Yes.  Think of cards as being for convenience instead of borrowing.  You don't have to carry large amounts of cash, can buy things on-line, don't have to walk into the store to get change from your gas fillup...

Comment: @jamesqf A debit card allows all of those, with studies showing that using a debit card results in less overall spending that using a credit card, even when paying off the entire balance monthly.

Comment: @Michael Richardson: But debit cards have many disadvantages, which have frequently been discussed here, so I won't repeat them.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson do these "studies" account for socioeconomic differences? I would expect that people who solely use a debit card have quite lower an income than people who solely use a credit card and pay off the balance in full every month.

Comment: "Crippling credit card debt", although an authentic aspect of the American experience, is one bit of adventure I suggest you don't experience.

Comment: On countries where this type of deal is common, the store is the one making you a loan in the price of the full product, and the credit card only manages the monthly payments (with no additional risk for them). So what you see as "0 interest rate", the interest is already included in the price of the product, and if you offer to pay the full price up front, you often get a huge "discount", which amounts to the interest embedded in the price. I am sure that taking a good loan deal will end up having the same overall effect, even with explicit interest rates.

Comment: While some answers have given examples of ways to go about obtaining 0% financing, I'd like to point out none of those are general solutions that can be applied to every product. The cases where you find 0% financing are generally quite rare.

Comment: If you want to do it in reverse, some stores still offer _Layaway_.  You pay $100 a month, and then, at the end of 10 months, you get the item.  It works well for things like Christmas gifts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible in some situations, but it's also difficult and risky. I personally have purchased computers, a bicycle, and many musical instruments and accessories using "interest-free" or "0%" financing. Here's how it works:

- First, you have to get a "store card". This is a credit card that you apply for with the retailer that you want to buy from. The card is actually issued by a third-party bank, and there are banks that make it their main business to issue cards for stores. Synchrony is an example of one such bank. Note that **most store cards do not allow interest-free financing**.
- If you qualify (which generally requires a good credit score and history), you will be issued the store card with a spending limit. Note that even though the card is issued by a third-party bank, you can only use a store card to purchase from the retailer it is for.
- After you are issued the card (which can happen in minutes - even though you haven't gotten the physical card in the mail, the retailer can use the details to charge your purchases right away), you choose a product or products sold by that retailer for which the retailer is offering the interest-free financing. You agree to purchase the product, and the total is applied to your balance on the store card, and you receive the item.

So, in order to do this, the retailer has to offer the interest free financing **and** you have to qualify for and obtain their special credit card. Retailers and banks only benefit from this arrangement when purchases are fairly expensive, so you normally can only find these offers at retailers that specialize in expensive products that are hobby or luxury goods. You may also find such deals at furniture or mattress stores and high-end electronics stores.

Once you've purchased an item like this, you want to make very sure you pay according to the terms. On the store cards I have used, the interest rate for purchases that are not paid off during the promotional period has generally been **22.50%** (APR). That is a **brutally high** interest rate. Compounding the risk is that the terms I have purchased under are such that if you don't pay off the balance in time, then all of the interest that would have accrued over the finance term is immediately applied to the balance, retroactively. So it's a big risk to take unless you are **certain** you can pay off the balance. Generally the only way to be that certain is to actually have that money in savings, in which case there isn't as much benefit to buying with no interest.

Also you'd want to pay careful attention to the difference between "24 months, no interest" and "24 equal payments, no interest". In the first case you can carry the full balance for 23 months and then pay off the total at the very end and be charged no interest. In the second case you must pay at least 1/24 of the total every month. If you miss a single month, you will be charged the full back interest and interest will start accruing going forward.

Some examples of retailers with interest-free financing:

Apple: https://www.apple.com/apple-card/monthly-installments/

Sweetwater: https://www.sweetwater.com/financing/

1-800 Mattress: https://www.1800mattress.com/convenient-financing-options.html

Bikes Online (and any place that allows PayPal Credit Buy Now, Pay Later): https://www.bikesonline.com/buy-now-pay-later-paypal/

And there are many others.

Comment: One note - you **can** use a store card at other retailers if the card is [co-branded](https://www.cnbc.com/select/co-branded-credit-cards/), meaning it uses a card issuer/network such as Visa, Mastercard, or American Express. For example, Amazon, Best Buy, and Macy's all currently offer both store-only and co-branded cards.

Comment: @TylerW Good point. Also the Apple Card is actually not exactly a store card and can be used for all kinds of purchases.

Comment: can you even get a store card without a SSN?

Comment: @rtaft I know you need a credit report with one of the major agencies. Whether that requires an SSN or TIN, I don’t know. It’s likely that it does.

Answer (score 59):

Trying to frame my advice in a way that *technically* answers the question:

Don't buy it right away. Pay $100/month to a savings account, and after ten months, buy the item with your accumulated $1000.

This doesn't work if you need the item *now*, but with some advance planning you can usually identify ahead of time what items you will need in the future.

Comment: This was my thought, too--of course this is not always easy, which is why converting future money to right now money has a cost.

Comment: That's a very good answer, provided it applies. Tough love is much better than enabling people getting debts with outrageous rates.

Comment: +1; I was going to answer this if no one else had done so already.

Comment: Save $100/mo for a year. After a year, ask yourself what you missed from not having it, then buy it on Craig's list for $100 and save $900 if you still need it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question...

Comment: I'm completely aware that I'm exploiting a technicality in the wording of the question: the OP never said they wanted to buy the item *now*, only that they want to make payments of $100/month without paying interest. I'm saying, the only way to do this in *general* is to make the payments to *yourself* (by saving) until you have enough to purchase the item with cash.

Comment: If you put 5 x $100 into a savings account and buy it then you are still financially a lot better off than buying right now. Actually, you pay interest on half the money ($500 instead of $1,000) for half the time (5 months instead of 10 months), so the total interest paid is only a quarter.

Comment: Optimizing the OP's cash is somewhat beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Agree that this doesn't answer the question. The question is about how credit cards work, not whether or not OP *should use* credit. We don't know how important the purchase is. Maybe it's something that would be more responsible to save up for, but maybe it's textbooks for classes that are about to start.

Comment: "That's not something you can do" It totally is. Plenty of credit cards and store cards offer 0% introductory rates for a year or more. I upvoted an answer that explains how they work as well as some of the gotchas.

Comment: The question was how to buy something with monthly payments without paying interest. That's not something you can do (again, in general) with a credit card, so I offered a solution the fit the criteria requested. (If the OP had explicitly specified that they needed the item now, and waiting to save the money was not an option, I would not have posted this answer.)

Comment: (Deleted and reposted my previous comment to fix a dumb typo.) Once again, I am talking about *in general*. Yes, some credit cards and stores provide X-days-same-as-cash promotions. Nothing in the question suggests that is an option.

Comment: I don't get what distinction you're making with "in general" here.

Comment: @Cody You can't assume you can pay 0% interest on any purchase you are interested in. If you are looking to buy a guitar amp or textbooks or a new car, it doesn't matter if your local furniture store offers 12-months-same-as-cash. The default position is, if you want to make payments over time, you'll have to pay interest. Any exceptions depend on what you are buying and from whom.

Comment: I'm not *just* talking about store-specific cards though. It takes a trivial amount of effort to find dozens of credit cards with 0% apr for a year, and they're completely agnostic about what particular product you're buying and from whom.

Comment: I don't care how trivial it is: it's not *universal*.

Answer (score 30):

> I am a **new** international student **in the US**

Aren't you here on an F-2 visa?

> that it's price is $1000, and I want to do the payment like $100 per month for 10 months (**with no extra interest**), how can I do it?

You can't, because there's a cost to borrow money.  (EDIT: 0% special offers are -- in my experience -- only offered to people with existing good credit.)

However, there are alternatives **for some purchases**: some stores offer "XX days (or months) same as cash".  That's usually only offered on expensive items at certain stores, and only for creditworthy customers. Or they jack up the price, to make up for the lost interest.

Comment: Yes I am on F-2 visa at the moment but I also will go on F-1 visa from the incoming fall.

Comment: So you say there is nothing like I will go to a store and say OK I want to buy this but I will pay the cost in few future months, $X per month?

Comment: "So you say there is nothing like...".  Re-read the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Yes, but I meant in general by credit cards not special offers of some stores in some times.

Comment: @chepner furniture and appliance stores usually offer "X months same as cash".  But that's certainly a subset of retailers.

Comment: @RonJohn: And that offer typically disappears when you bargain.

Comment: @chepner are they special promotions?  I don't buy this stuff very often, but seem to recall that it's a standard practice.

Comment: @MSalters absolutely right; they've got to pay for the loan somehow.

Comment: I remember one furniture store that offered 0%, 36 months for anything... or 10% discount if you pay immediately 

Comment: A common trick is they will offer something like "0% for 12 months", but will jack up the interest to something really high if you DON'T pay it off in full by the end of the 12 months. They will also set the minimum payment so it actually takes something like 36 months if you only pay that, so it is easy to get fooled into paying a lot of interest if you don't read the fine print.

Comment: A common trick is they will offer something like "0% for 12 months", but will jack up the interest to something really high if you DON'T pay it off in full by the end of the 12 months. And then they'll help you set up automated payments that automates 11 payments, so you have to remember to pay that 12th one yourself. If you forget, then that super high interest rate kicks in.

Comment: student visa is F-1, not F2

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica OP has asked many questions, and previously has said he's here on an F-2.

Comment: @SethR I'm not sure if this is still legal but I recall getting 0% financing where, if you didn't pay it off by the end of the initial period, you owed interest on the entire loan, not just the remaining balance.

Comment: @JimmyJames, yup, that is common too. I had a loan like that once, but made very sure to have it paid off before the introductory period. It can be a great deal if you know what you are doing, but bite you hard if you don't.

Comment: @SethR Same here.  They must have done the math and realized that enough people don't pay to make it worthwhile.  I tend to think that most people asking questions here would at least attempt to pay but I guess it's hard to know what might happen in the next year or two.  In general, even though CC rates are high, it can be better than the alternative e.g. sleeping on the floor.  I'd rather pay 20 bucks a month in interest than be in pain for months trying to save up for decent bed.

Comment: @JimmyJames there's plenty of alternatives between "sleeping on the floor" and "expensive bed" (all decent beds are expensive).

Comment: @MooingDuck It's not a trick. e.g. Home Depot does the no interest for 12 months thing if you use their credit card, which I do all the time. When you log in to pay, you have a very clear choice betweeen "Pay in full", "Pay the minimum amount" and "Pay the minimum amount to avoid interest". If people still get confused and end up getting hit with interest, then TBH they have no-one to blame but themselves.

Comment: @Eugene: You appear to be talking about a different scenario. There are some places that set up automated payments that in the small text don't make the last payment, tricking customers into paying the full interest rate at the last moment.  It's not super common, but it does exist.

Comment: @MooingDuck No, this is the exact scenario I was talking about. My contractor was recently bitching about the "deviousness" of the Home Depo credit card, because he was charged all the missing interest since he didn't pay his off in time, even though he was making regular payments. I told him: so why didn't you just pay the "minimum amount to avoid interest"? And he was like "what's that?" I showed him on the site and it's pretty obvious and he said that it's "devious" that the default selected option is "minimum payment" 

Comment: @Eugene TBH, I've never heard of a "minimum amount to avoid interest".  Chase and BoA only have "full amount due", "minimum payment" and "custom".

Comment: @RonJohn To get to $20 a month, I used $1500 as the price at 16%.  I think you can find a decent bed at that price easily.

Comment: I can't help but recommend this -- obscene as usual -- [Louis CK video](https://youtu.be/Y_-1l_SlA7c?t=19) detailing how your bank charges go up when you are broke: "Have you ever been so poor that the bank starts charging you money because you don't have enough ... money?" "15 dollars, that's how much it costs to only have 20 dollars."

Comment: @RonJohn Chase and BoA are banks, that's how they make money. Home Depot, Lowes, Costco and other stores that you can get credit cards from, give you credit so that you can buy their stuff. The card is administered by a bank like Citi, so it'll take it's pound of flesh if you let it, but the stores themselves actually want you to buy their stuff when you want it, pay it off interest free and be happy to do it again, so they make it straightforward.

Comment: @Eugene I did not deny that it exists, only that I'd never heard of it.  Nothing more.

Comment: @JimmyJames if you're poor, $1500 is a lot.  Even $20 is a lot.  Thus, you find a cheap bed, since it's what you can afford, and it's better than sleeping on the floor.

Comment: @RonJohn And if you can't afford to buy that cheap bed with cash, I think paying interest (and paying it down) is an acceptable solution.  That's my only point.  In a lot of situations, the alternative (e.g. renting thing you need) is more expensive than the 16% interest, as high as it is.

Comment: The op won't even be eligible for the majority of credit cards without a SSN.  The interest rates will be even higher for those that allow using passports.

Comment: @SethR : once I needed to buy something very expensive, and I already had about 3/4 of the money, and it would have been very nice if I could have started using my purchase half a year earlier than when all the money would have been accumulated. And they offered credit, and they said that if I payed at least half up-front, they could give one at a much reduced interest rate, and as I already had 3/4 up-front, they offered an even more amazingly low interest rate! ...

Comment: ... but I noticed that the interest rate was not calculated on the money they were to loan me, but on the full price, so I would have had to pay interest for *my own* money! A quick calculation proved that if I had no up-front money whatsoever and took the "higher" interest loan, I would have payed less in total! When I confronted them with this, they first tried to deny it, repeating that I understood it wrong, and "lower interest is always better", but when I showed the calculations they just shrugged "well we offer different options, the clients should choose what they think is best".

Answer (score 20):

When you use a credit card and pay over time, you will pay plenty of interest. 16% to 20% a year is not unusual. So the wrong way to do things: Buy a $1,000 item with your credit card. Pay $100 every month. (Because interest will add up very very quickly). A better way to do things: Buy a $1,000 item with your credit card. Reduce your spending as much as possible so you can pay back as much as possible every month, like $350 a month for three months. In this example, this will save you about $100.

A better way is to get money at a lower rate, for example a bank loan. This will be harder to get, but much cheaper. A bank loan will almost always be the best you can get.

Or buy things that come with a low cost or interest free loan. But be careful: One shop might offer something for $1,000 with an interest free loan, while another shop charges $900 for the exact same product without an interest free loan.

And don't believe any salesman. Or saleswoman. Or salesperson. They only want your best - and your best is your money.

Answer (score 8):

As a general rule you will pay interest if you pay your balance on a credit card over time. The credit card company is providing a service (loaning you money), and that service costs money.

That said, you can often find credit card offers that give you a promotional rate of 0% for some fixed amount of time when you first sign up. I suppose you could keep signing up for new cards and transferring your balance to avoid paying interest.

Another option is that for expensive purchases, many stores will offer a no-interest payment plan to entice you to make a purchase. Be aware, however, that they often start accruing interest after a certain amount of time if you don't pay off the balance in full.

Comment: Aren't those promotional rate cards only offered on balance transfers to relatively credit-worthy people?

Comment: Yeah, probably. I'm just trying to give OP some options for a fairly unreasonable ask of "give me something of value for free"

Answer (score 7):

**[Layaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layaway)**

You won't be able to do this with a credit card, as their entire business is built around buy-now, pay-more-later.  It may be more difficult to find, but some stores offer Layaway, where you pick out an item, and the store holds it for you until you make the last payment.  You don't get it until you've paid in full, but in many cases, the store doesn't charge interest.

**Be careful with the layaway fine print**

Many stores will charge a small fee to open a layaway account.  You'll have to bring 10%-15% up front.  You also will pay weekly, not monthly, and the most generous term will be 90 days.  If you end up not paying they will keep at least some of your payments, usually as a restocking fee.  You also generally won't be able to get hot-ticket items this way as the store can easily find someone with cash-in-hand.  And some stores charge some interest as they are essentially extending you credit and holding product for you.

The best way to buy is always cash in hand.

**Public Service Announcement about college and credit cards**

Credit card companies [target](https://money.cnn.com/2008/07/10/pf/credit_cards_college/) [college](https://www.thebalance.com/credit-card-companies-love-college-students-960090) [students](https://www.newsweek.com/credit-card-issuers-still-target-college-students-82771).  They know they'll run it up, and either spend years making the minimum payments, or mom and dad will pay it off.

If you have no credit, go to a bank and get a secured card for $1000.  A secured card is a credit card where you open an account with the spending limit.  If you can't pay, then the credit union will just use that account.  Don't carry it with you and make a few purchases a year on it and pay it off immediately.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that layaway isn't usually free. You pay a fee to set it up and could pay additional fees if you do not finish paying for the item. If you have a hard time controlling your spending habits then this could be a good way to commit to a purchase but realistically you should just set your money aside and pay in full at a future date. A future date has the benefit of buying that latest model which is important for a commodity such as a T.V. I am 99% sure Wal-Mart only offers layaway during the holiday season by the way.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - You're right.  Your better off just saving the money yourself and paying cash-in-hand.  Even if layaway is free, saving it yourself means you'll get a newer product, and there is 0 risk of being charged fees or losing your layaway deposits.

Comment: Layaway is **completely a scam** built on a (false) FOMO (fear of missing out). You don't get **anything at all** for the fees you pay and risk of them keeping your money if you fail to keep paying.

Comment: I reckon I can guess, but with layaway, what happens if the store goes out of business when you've paid for 90% of an item you haven't received?

Comment: @ChrisH Are you assuming a responsible or irresponsible business? Stores don't generally shut down and pack up overnight and if they do then they were probably not big enough to offer layaway. The customer would likely be contacted and offered the chance to pay off and receive the item. They would rather have this person buy the item since the alternative is to sell it at a liquidated price. If the customer declines to buy out the item then the store might just give it to them if the liquidated price is forecasted to be lower than the 90% already paid.

Comment: @ChrisH I've never used layaway but my understanding is that the items gets physically reserved so it's not like they would liquidate their unpaid layaway stock without settling things with the debtors first.

Comment: @ChrisH Regardless of this conjecture, read your layaway contract before signing since it will outline your responsibilities along with the store's. If you feel you got screwed during a store closing then read your contract again to make sure you understood it because a lawyer isn't really going to care about the $500 T.V. that someone couldn't afford unless the store systematically reneged people's layaway contracts.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm the other side of the Atlantic, where it doesn't exist, but credit terms on goods are quite common (some interest free funded by marked-up prices, some at extortionate rates, and lots in between).  So I'm mainly curious about the risks.  We've had some big retailers fail over the last few years, and more with covid.  A common theme is that gift card balances are unsecured debt and lost. These balances can be quite large, and may be used as a way of saving for an item by topping up until there's enough on the card - similar to layaway but not against a particular item

Comment: ... It's not my sort of thing TBH, but that's partly because I can afford to save and have modest tastes (several credit cards cleared in full every month, no debt except mortgage, I even avoid subscription services...).  It sounds risky anyway

Comment: @ChrisH So what are you asking about exactly: layaway terms? gift card terms? which businesses act responsibly versus irresponsibly when they go out of business? how do store-branded credit cards work? why do stores love selling gift cards?

Comment: "And some stores charge some interest as they are essentially extending you credit and holding product for you." That's evil.  In truth, you're loaning _them_ money. Logically, you should be charging _them_ interest. :(

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I was asking about layaway as it's new to me. Of course there may be legal protection of customers' money but I suspect that when a company goes out of business is too late for them to act responsibly. The time to look after other people's money is when the company takes it, not when the creditors are out for all they can get.   The bit about gift cards mostly explains where I'm coming from.

Comment: @ChrisH On this side of the Atlantic you are able to use your gift cards right up until the store's final day of operation; large chains can take months to close. One would assume that layaway items need to be settled before the final day as well. It's very difficult to be unaware that a store is closing soon if you're making payments on one of their items.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus fair enough; here it's variable.  Our corporate bankruptcy laws are quite different.  Still if the full balance became due or lose what you've already paid, that could be bad, but it's academic from my point of view, as I'd avoid it even if available. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @ChrisH You can read Walmart's specific terms here https://www.walmart.com/cp/layaway/1088466 and I'm sure they'd give you a booklet with fine print if you actually initiate layaway. If they demanded full payment immediately then many customers would likely opt to just cancel and live with the cancellation fee. I think a huge chain like Walmart would probably offer financing through a 3rd party. If Walmart didn't behave amicably then lawyers would have a field day. Maintaining poise is in the company's best interest or else their bankruptcy will get a whole lot more expensive.

Comment: I've never used Layaway, but it was developed as a mechanism to allow folks who live paycheck-to-paycheck to have a way of buying big things without _blowing the bank_.  I'm old (in my 60s).  When I was a kid, there was a push at back-to-school time to pick out your kids' Christmas gifts and buy them on layaway.  It was a way for retailers to sell more stuff to people who couldn't afford to pay for them all at once.  There are lots of scams that take advantage of folks without money, but, at least traditionally, layaway wasn't in that category.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, **you** (specifically you) are extremely unlikely to just get a free loan especially as an international student. I would be amazed if you could qualify for a credit card at all.

Anyways, if you did qualify for a credit card then it would likely be for 25% APR.

Charging $1,000 to this credit card will cost you:

- $111.81 per month for 10 months; $1,118.12

or

- $212.67 per month for 5 months; $1,063.36

It's simple, paying off the loan faster results in less interest paid.

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, at least, there are quite a few credit providers who operate "buy now, pay later" schemes. Perhaps the most well-known of these is [Klarna](https://klarna.com/), which does also operate in the US. Beware, though: if you fail to make your repayments on time, you will be hit with extremely high interest.

Some of these schemes have come under scrutiny recently because many merchants offer them as quick checkout options, allowing customers to easily take out such lines of credit without being fully aware of the terms they're agreeing to.

Answer (score 3):

Every answer so far assumes you're financially illiterate and have no self control or planning ability. While I typically agree with the warnings provided, credit card offers and rewards can be valuable to take advantage of if you're very careful, plan accordingly, and have a high attention to detail. Personally I've received thousands of dollars in bonuses and rewards "playing the system". If you ask me to compare it to my time spent - I could probably pick up a second job and do just as well, but I enjoy this more.

Now, typically, if you were to purchase a $1,000 on an average credit card in the US, and aim to pay $100/month, you'd actually be paying for 11 months, with an 89.11 bill on the last. That's your total interest.
With that in mind, you may want to [look here](https://www.aie.org/resources/tools-and-calculators/credit-card-calculator/) if you do *need* to plan purchasing with credit.

With the above in mind, your goal of buying something for $1,000 and paying it off in 10 months is very doable. Be warned of getting into the wrong mindset, or falling into a pattern of purchasing on credit without paying in full monthly... but a quick google search for "0% APR credit card no prior credit" gives plenty of options. These will be the gimmick-iest and most predatory offers though. Once again, see the wealth of valuable information already provided here. But if you're really looking to, have the time to actually read all the terms and conditions, and are careful throughout the process (setting reminders for payment dates or other needed actions) you absolutely can do this with (imo) a reasonable amount of effort. This is where your attention to detail is key.

I'd pay into a fund like the top answer suggests if I were you, for now, assuming its an option. Just wanted to add some more detail/resources.

P.S. I only didn't link to real offers as I don't think that's allowed in the SE - and like I said, in your situation, I wouldn't. I built my credit for 5+ years before "playing the system" and benefitting from promotions, rewards, or deferred/0 interest.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. Some people say if you use intro 0% APR that's fine for avoiding the extra money payment, but it causes bad/negative effect on credit score, because the 35% of the scoring formula is about payment history., is it true?

Comment: As long as you're paying the correct amounts on time, it shouldn't have a negative impact on credit. Most break downs on credit scoring are very rough estimates - the three major bureaus are private entities and while they follow a standard, it does change over time, and between the bureaus.

Answer (score 2):

### This line of thinking is the real danger

> If I get a new credit card in the US with a $2000 credit line/limit and want to buy something whose price is $1000, and I want to do the payment like $100 per month for 10 months (with no extra interest), how can I do it? What is the procedure and the mechanism?

You just charge it to the card.

The interest is just a matter of perception.  Think of the REAL price as the price *with interest* (e.g. $1100).  Do you want to buy that thing for $1100?  If so, put it on the card and pay $110 for 10 months.

If you are saying "how do I get it without paying interest", that is just money-grubbing, trying to get something for nothing.  **That line of thinking is the real danger to you**. Because your quest for that "free lunch" will lead you into a ton of very bad deals from predators trying to take advantage of the stupid.  **There is no free lunch**.   If you don't want to pay interest, then save $100 for 10 months and buy it *at the end* of the 10 months.

From a comment:

> Also: DON'T! It's a trap to get you hooked in an endless cycle of debt, consumerism and paycheck to paycheck living

Debt slavery.  Granted it's not as bad as the real slavery found in the third world, but it *feels* as bad to the victims.

But that's only a problem for those with poor needs control.  If you gotta have it and you're willing to do a deal with the devil, then you're a debt-slave, but you do have that shiny gadget. *Oh wait, it was a cheap Chinese piece-o'junk, and it already broke.*

The worst of this is with cars and cell phones, when they will happily sell you a new car *even though your existing car is "upside down" (owing more on the car than it's worth)*, and will simply **fold that debt into the new loan/lease**.  Since the financially uneducated usually don't allow themselves ANY spare money to buy out of that hole, their only exit path becomes signing loans on bigger and bigger new cars, with bigger and bigger monthly payments.  Eventually the house of cars comes tumbling down, and they wind up bankrupt, and there are people who will finance cars for the bankrupt on even *worse* terms.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. Interest is most certainly not "just a matter of perception."